# How to explain the code used to implement va_arg and va_start in tcc's stdarg.h?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, compilation, x86-64

```
struct __va_list_struct
{
    unsigned int gp_offset;
    unsigned int fp_offset;
    union {
        unsigned int overflow_offset;
        char* overflow_arg_area;
    };
    char* reg_save_area;
};

typedef struct __va_list_struct* va_list;

/* we use __builtin_(malloc|free) to avoid #define malloc tcc_malloc */
/* XXX: this lacks the support of aggregated types. */
#define va_start( ap, last )                                                  \
    ( ap = (va_list)__builtin_malloc ( sizeof ( struct __va_list_struct ) ),  \
      *ap = *(struct __va_list_struct*)( (char*)__builtin_frame_address ( 0 ) \
                                         - 16 ),                              \
      ap->overflow_arg_area                                                   \
      = ( (char*)__builtin_frame_address ( 0 ) + ap->overflow_offset ),       \
      ap->reg_save_area = (char*)__builtin_frame_address ( 0 ) - 176 - 16 )
#define va_arg( ap, type )                                                     \
    ( *(type*)( __builtin_types_compatible_p ( type, long double )             \
                    ? ( ap->overflow_arg_area += 16,                           \
                        ap->overflow_arg_area - 16 )                           \
                    : __builtin_types_compatible_p ( type, double )            \
                          ? ( ap->fp_offset < 128 + 48                         \
                                  ? ( ap->fp_offset += 16,                     \
                                      ap->reg_save_area + ap->fp_offset - 16 ) \
                                  : ( ap->overflow_arg_area += 8,              \
                                      ap->overflow_arg_area - 8 ) )            \
                          : ( ap->gp_offset < 48                               \
                                  ? ( ap->gp_offset += 8,                      \
                                      ap->reg_save_area + ap->gp_offset - 8 )  \
                                  : ( ap->overflow_arg_area += 8,              \
                                      ap->overflow_arg_area - 8 ) ) ) )
```

The definition of first structure especially confuses me.

The next is macro — `va_start()`.

The final is macro — `va_arg()`.

And all of above is used in x86_64 platform ...

Can you explain what this code does?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you understand what `va_end()` does?  If it is more than a no-op, can you show it for completeness, and because it might be enlightening.  Have you created a tiny function which uses the code and looked at the preprocessed output?  Did you reformat the preprocessed output so it was more nearly readable?  Did you make appropriate allowance for the fact that they must be macros?  You have to know quite a lot about x86_64 to know what some of those magic numbers are (176, 192, 48, …).

Comment: Yes, I understand what va_end() does. It just free the pointer named ap and set it to NULL

Comment: You should read all of section 3.5.7 of the [System V 64-bit ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) that describes in general what is going on here.

Comment: Thank you !...! That troubles me almost one week...

Comment: Perhaps you can copy the contents of each macro into a function, and then debug it step by step. Would most likely help you to understand it (I'm guessing you might need to declare some global variables for these two functions).

Comment: Thank you for your answering , but I have tried it since i found that macro in the source codes of `tcc` .